# WordPress - Месячный архив определенной категории

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести список ссылок месячных архивов определенной категории?

Делаю вот так `/2017/03/?cat=113`

Список с самой категории я вывел, но когда нахожусь в одном из месяцев, не могу подхватить `id` категории.

С помощью шаблонов не нравится решение, так как имеется более 50 категорий.

Если какой-нибудь еще способ решить задачу?

Пример:

```html
if ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_archive() ) { 
 $currentCat = get_query_var('cat');
} ;
  
$year_prev = null;
$months = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
        YEAR( post_date ) AS year,
        COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( )
        and post_type = 'post'
        GROUP BY month , year
        ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($months as $month) :
 $year_current = $month->year;
 if ($year_current != $year_prev){
  if ($year_prev != null){?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
 <h3><?php echo $month->year; ?></h3>
 <ul class="list-group">
 <?php } ?>
 <li>
  <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?>/?cat=<?php echo $currentCat; ?>">
   <span class="archive-month"><?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></span>
   <span class="archive-count"><?php echo $month->post_count; ?></span>
  </a>
 </li>
<?php $year_prev = $year_current;
endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Приведите свой код, из вопроса ничего не понятно, где и как вы подхватываете.

Answer (score 1):

Не проще обычным WP_Query делать с импользыванием date_query ?
Например:

```
$args = array(
'cat' => 113,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'relation' => 'AND',
'date_query' => array(
  'after' => '1 months ago'
  )
'orderby' => 'date'
);
$date_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Даный запрос даст все посты из категории 113 опусбликованые за последний месяц, в порядке публикаций.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как мне перечислить все месяцы ?

Comment: Что иемеется ввиду под всема месяцами ? 
Можно использывать  в запросе даты комбинированые `'before'` и `after` и многое другое, почитайте об `date_query` например сдесь: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Comment: Спасибо. Понял.